# Reply with string to function on JSON success

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, json

I would like to send a back to the JS function a message when the JSON returned.
As you can see below I was trying to insert the message into the JSON reply but I got `[object][object]`
and not the message. how can I read the message?

Here is my code:

**Controller:**

```
 public ActionResult UpdateCategory(Category category)
    {

         // do something.



     // I want to send this message back to the function:
        var message = "some message to reply."  


      // I was trying this:
      // return Json(new { success = true, message = message }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);


     return Json(new { success = true }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

**Script**

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/UpdateCategory",
    data: formData,
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    success: function (message) {  

       alert(message); // I would like to show here the message.                

    },
    error: function () {
        $('.overlay').hide();
        alert("error");

    }

});
```

Comment: Use the `console` to view objects - `alert` will always show the `[object]` syntax.

Comment: using the old return you would have needed `alert(message.message)` to get the actual message string

Comment: What do you mean "old return" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put this line back:

```
return Json(new { success = true, message = message }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

then change

```
alert(message);
```

to

```
alert (message.message)
```